# How to create a mask from NLCD data in Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to create a rangeland mask from 2016 NLCD data in Google Earth Engine. The basic approach I'm trying to take is to import the NLCD asset, filter to the 2016 data, and then use ee.ImageCollection.remap() function to create a mask. My code is as follows:

```
var nlcd = ee.ImageCollection('USGS/NLCD')
                          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', 'NLCD2016')) // Get 2016 Data
                          .select(0) // Get Landcover band integer
                          .aside(print,'2016 NLCD'); //Returns ImageCollection with 1 element
```

Next I invoke remap. I'm trying to map values 51:74 to 1 (these values correspond to range and shrubland classification).

```
var nlcdRange = nlcd.remap([51, 52, 71, 72, 73, 74],
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      'landcover_class_values') // problem here? 
                      .aside(print,'NLCD Range Mask'); // returns empty ImageCollection
```

*nlcdRange* is an empty ImageCollection object. I think I specified the *columnName* property incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `remap` can be applied on a collection and on an image. In the first case, it will remap the value of a property of each feature/image. The second case remaps pixel values. You are probably looking for the second one. your variable `nlcd` is a imageCollection. To apply the `remap` function, we have to apply that on each image in the that collection. Therefore we map over image in the collection:

```
var nlcdRange = nlcd.map(function(image){
  return image.remap([51, 52, 71, 72, 73, 74],
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]); 
});
```

By default, it uses the first band of the image and masked all other values. In your case, the first is correct as you pre-selected one band, although for the second, you might want to set all other values to zero to use the output as a mask. Also, your image collection contains just of one image, so you'd probably just interested in transforming that image collection to an image. See the link for those suggestions.

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b9e5c827e80c95b1232d8a192bcf3afa)